# Redis not allowing any operations

Tags: redis

I have a Redis server. When I try the `ping` command or any other command using `redis-cli ping` I get an error message saying:

```
(error) ERR operation not permitted
```

typing only `redis-cli` takes me to the prompt:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

after this any redis command again gives the same error. I have no idea what the issue could be. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which commands are you running?

Comment: Ping, get, set.. none of them work. All give the same error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your `redis.conf` file - is there a `requirepass` field that is set (and not commented out with `#`) - if so, you need to authenticate first like this:

```
AUTH Pwd  (replace Pwd with actual password phrase)
```

Once authenticated, you can issue new commands.

Answer (score 1):

`requirepass` option may be enabled in your configuration file `redis.conf` by default

- Pass the authenticated with `-a` argument after `redis-cli` command:

  ```
  $ redis-cli -a YourPass
  ```
- exec `auth` command after redis prompt:

  ```
  > auth YourPass
  ```